# convert dataframe to dictionary with multiple values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with values as:

```
    Agent Name  Team    Available for production    Product Type    Air/Non-Air PCC key
0   Anjani Aggarwal APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 0R0B    0R0B_AIR_Fresh
1   Anjani Aggarwal APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 4H9B    4H9B_AIR_Fresh
2   Anjani Aggarwal APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 56HB    56HB_AIR_Fresh
3   Anjani Aggarwal APAC    True    Fresh   LAND    0R0B    0R0B_LAND_Fresh
4   Anjani Aggarwal APAC    True    Fresh   LAND    B9YJ    B9YJ_LAND_Fresh
5   Anjani Aggarwal APAC    True    Fresh   LAND    G6MJ    G6MJ_LAND_Fresh
6   Rohit Gusain    APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 0R0B    0R0B_AIR_Fresh
7   Rohit Gusain    APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 4H9B    4H9B_AIR_Fresh
8   Rohit Gusain    APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 56HB    56HB_AIR_Fresh
9   Rohit Gusain    APAC    True    Fresh   LAND    0R0B    0R0B_LAND_Fresh
10  Rohit Gusain    APAC    True    Fresh   LAND    B9YJ    B9YJ_LAND_Fresh
11  Rohit Gusain    APAC    True    Fresh   LAND    G6MJ    G6MJ_LAND_Fresh
12  Sakshi Malhotra APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 0R0B    0R0B_AIR_Fresh
13  Sakshi Malhotra APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 4H9B    4H9B_AIR_Fresh
14  Sakshi Malhotra APAC    True    Fresh   AIR 56HB    56HB_AIR_Fresh
15  Sakshi Malhotra APAC    True    Fresh   LAND    0R0B    0R0B_LAND_Fresh
```

I need to convert this dataframe into a dictionary like:

```
dict={'Anjani Aggarwal':['0R0B_AIR_Fresh','4H9B_AIR_Fresh','56HB_AIR_Fresh','0R0B_LAND_Fresh','B9YJ_LAND_Fresh','G6MJ_LAND_Fresh'],
'Rohit Gusain':['0R0B_AIR_Fresh','4H9B_AIR_Fresh','56HB_AIR_Fresh','0R0B_LAND_Fresh','B9YJ_LAND_Fresh','G6MJ_LAND_Fresh']
}
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have correctly setup the dataframe (`df`), you can `group_by` your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Convert the dataframe to a dictionary
dict_data = df.groupby('Agent Name')['PCC key'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

You can more informations into the [group_by documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)